# How to decode a (doubly) 'url-encoded' string in python

Tags: python, urlencode, urldecode

Tried decoding a `url-encoded` string in the following way

```
some_string = 'FireShot3%2B%25282%2529.png'
import urllib
res = urllib.unquote(some_string).decode()
res
u'FireShot3+%282%29.png'
```

Original string is `FireShot3 (2).png`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer:
`urllib.unquote_plus(urllib.unquote_plus(some_string))` due to double encoding.

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566069/url-decode-utf-8-in-python 100%

Comment: @MarcusMüller: not quite. There is no UTF-8 encoded data there, the string has been URL encoded **twice**.

Comment: In Python 2, 3 or both? The library fn used will differ

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your input is encoded *double*. Using Python 3:

```
urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.unquote(some_string))
```

Output:

```
'FireShot3+(2).png'
```

now you have the `+` left.

**Edit:**

Using Python 2.7, it would need to be:

```
urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote('FireShot3%2B%25282%2529.png'))
```

Comment: `unqoute_plus` handles the `+` character.

Answer (score 10):

`urllib.unquote_plus(urllib.unquote_plus(some_string))
FireShot3 (2).png`