# Python requests r.text doesn't decode properly paypal API

Tags: python, python-requests, decode

```
import requests
import datetime

server_addr = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp"

headers = {'content-type': 'text/plain'}

params = {
    'method'        :'BMButtonSearch',
    'version'       :'124.0',
    'user'          :'xxx',
    'pwd'           :'xxx',
    'signature'     :'xxx',
    'startdate'     :datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
}

r = requests.post(server_addr, headers=headers, data=params)
r.encoding='utf-8'
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

200

> TIMESTAMP=2016%2d04%2d07T04%3a40%3a13Z&CORRELATIONID=1b4a043b2afe&ACK=Success&VERSION=124%2e0&BUILD=000000
>
> r.text
>   u'TIMESTAMP=2016%2d04%2d07T04%3a40%3a13Z&CORRELATIONID=1b4a043b2afe&ACK=Success&VERSION=124%2e0&BUILD=000000'
>   **<-- This isn't decoded or broken into key/value pairs as expected. It is just one large string.**

Additional Information:

```
r.encoding
'utf-8'

r.headers
{'Content-Length': '106', 'Set-Cookie': 'X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE11.APIT.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher_apit%26TIME%3D2917401943; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Connection': 'close', 'Paypal-Debug-Id': '1b4a043b2afe', 'X-PAYPAL-OPERATION-NAME': 'BMButtonSearch', 'Date': 'Thu, 07 Apr 2016 04:40:13 GMT', 'X-PAYPAL-API-RC': '', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', 'HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR': 'dcg12.slc'}
```

Comment: Why would that be expected? [The docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/api/#requests.Response.text) don't mention anything about `text` doing any parsing.

Comment: Requests will automatically decode content from the server. -->  http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: You're confusing decoding with parsing. Note the example: `>>> r.text =>
u'[{"repository":{"open_issues":0,"url":"https://github.com/...` That's a string you get back, not a dictionary.

Comment: You just quoted example output which looks nothing like the output I get.  Therefore the output I get is unexpected.  It is neither decoded nor parsed.  You are seeing the %2d which are clear examples of URL encoding.

Comment: It's URL-encoded, which isn't the kind of decoding Requests does by default. To decode and parse in one step, look at my answer below, which works on the string in your question.

`This isn't ... as expected. It is just one large string.` That's exactly what's expected when you call `text` on a `Response` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that format looks like a query string, you can use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) from the standard library to parse it:

```
print(urlparse.parse_qs(r.text))
```

Edit: If all you want is to unencode the string (but leave it as a string), use [`urllib.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote):

```
print(urllib.unquote(r.text))
```

(see this answer here: [How to decode a 'url-encoded' string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431359/how-to-decode-a-url-encoded-string-in-python))