# Translate \ucweirdnumberscharacters into English?

Tags: python, character, decode

there is something in JSON that says

```
"title":{"rendered":"[\ubcf4\ub3c4\uc790\ub8cc] \uc2a4\uc2a4\ub85c \uc9c0\ud0a4\ub294 \uc18c\uc911\ud55c \uac1c\uc778\uc815\ubcf4  \ube57\uc378, \u2018\ube44\ubc00\ubc88\ud638 \ubcc0\uacbd\ud558\uae30\u2019 \ubcf4\uc548 \ucea0\ud398\uc778 \uc2e4\uc2dc"}
```

how can I convert this rendered \ubcf4 stuff into English?

i'm not even sure what this stuff is called so i'm not sure what to google for..

any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Pass the entire thing into [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

Comment: Can you give us more details? Those look like python representation of JSON characters so the question is how they got there. Is this literally the serialized JSON? Python after loading the JSON? Is it from the `print` function? Did you load this with `json.loads`? It may be as simple as `foo = json.loads('somefile.json', encoding='utf-8'))` which is the normal way to load json.

Comment: @metatoaster - thanks. how would i translate this? "%ec%9e%85%ec%b6%9c%ea%b8%88-%ec%84%9c%eb%b9%84%ec%8a%a4-%ec%a7%80%ec%97%b0-%ec%95%88%eb%82%b4" - it is converted to 입출금-서비스-지연-안내 which is then translated to 
Deposit - Service - Delay - Information. how can i make it directly go from that %characters to English?

Comment: Where are you getting the % encoding from? That's not in the question.  Anyway, check this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566069/url-decode-utf-8-in-python) for the different solutions in python 2 and python 3.