# How to convert and assign properly an unicode string?

Tags: python, decode, python-2.x, urlencode

My problem is the following:

1. I get from a google search query the following unicode string: `"Playa de Porc%C3%ADa"`.
2. I need to correctly convert `"Playa de Porc%C3%ADa" into "Playa de Porcía"` to pass that new string to a function that will do another search.
3. The problem is that the accent `"í"` is `cd ad` in Unicode, I have tried to use `decode()` and `encode()` in several ways but can't get to the point.

Regards!

Edit: My code is in Python2.

Comment: That's not a Unicode string. That's a percent-encoded string (also called URL-encoding). Unicode strings are those you see on every web site, including StackOverflow itself. They don't need special handling which is why I can write `Αυτό Εδώ` or `Playa de Porcía` and know that SO will display it properly without any encoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Url decode UTF-8 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566069/url-decode-utf-8-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

That's not a Unicode string. That's a percent-encoded string

for example `%20` is a space symbol
https://www.url-encode-decode.com/ - online url decoder

python 2 verison

```
import urllib2
print urllib2.unquote("Playa de Porc%C3%ADa")
```

python 3 verison

```
import urllib
urllib.parse.unquote("Playa de Porc%C3%ADa")
```

code for all versions

```
try:
    from urllib import unquote
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import unquote

print(unquote("Playa de Porc%C3%ADa"))
```

output

```
'Playa de Porcía'
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: You should explain that this URL encoding, not any kind of Unicode string. Otherwise the use of `urllib` won't make a lot of sense

Comment: Sorry, i should have commented it. My code is in python 2.

Comment: @javier I added example for python2