# How to write re_path url in django for reading special character?

Tags: python, regex, django, model

I am working with Django URL pattern for my project. I am sending a String containing **special characters** and **numbers**. While reading a string in python function it won't get the **?** in a function.

**html**

```
{% for user_name in userSet%}
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/slackNotification/{{user_name}}/{{data.question}}">{{ user_name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**url**

```
path('slackNotification/<str:slack_user_name>/<str:question>',views.slackNotification)
```

When I get the all details through URL then string whichever I received in the python code it won't contain **?** mark even though my input contains Special characters and numbers.

*input*: What is your name?
*output*: What is your name(question mark not available;)

**Question**
I have tried this:

```
re_path(r'^slackNotification/<str:slack_user_name>/(?P<question>\w+)',views.slackNotification)
```

**Output**
The current path didn't match any of the url

I want to know the exact regular expression for my requirement ??

Comment: A `?` in a url indicates the end of the path and the beginning of the list of query parameters, like in `http://example.com/apples?color=green` the path is `http://example.com/apples`, and `{'color': 'green'}` is the query dict. Only the part before the `?` is considered to be the path. So if you want to include a `?` in a URL you should URL-encode it: `%3F`. Same is true for other special characters, a space for example is `%20`

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you so much for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `path()` is correct as long as each path component in your URL is URL-encoded. `?` is a special character in URLs: It denotes the end of the path and anything coming after it is interpreted as query parameters:

```
http://www.example.com/apples?color=green
```

has the path `http://www.example.com/apples` and a query parameter `color` with value `green`.

Therefore, if you want to the string "What is your name?" to be included in your path, you need to make sure it's URL-encoded: `What%20is%20your%20name%3F` where `%3F` is the URL-encoded `?` and `%20` is for `<space>`.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the above solution please refer [Url decode UTF-8 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566069/url-decode-utf-8-in-python) link for more information on urllib.parse.quote and urllib.parse.unquote