# How to map latin letters in hex format to its corresponding latin letter in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, latin

I was trying to extract data from the web. Few of the letters which were in latin were coming in its plain hex format.

For eg :

```
https://www.zomato.com/ncr/café-mrp-connaught-place-new-delhi
```

this link would become

```
https://www.zomato.com/ncr/caf%C3%A9-mrp-connaught-place-new-delhi
```

How do I get the latin letter back from this. I want to generalize this and do it for all the latin letters that gets changed in my dataframe.

```
i=1
main_page_url = r"https://www.zomato.com/ncr/connaught-place-delhi-restaurants"
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\HPO2KOR\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
wd = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
wd.get(main_page_url)
while(i<=2):
    rests = wd.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="result-title hover_feedback zred bold ln24   fontsize0 "]')
    for rest in rests:
        df = df.append({'Rest Name' : rest.text,
                   'URL' : rest.get_attribute("href")}, ignore_index=True)
    nxt_pg = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="paginator_item   next item"]')
    nxt_pg.click()
    wd.switch_to_window(wd.window_handles[0])
    i+=1
wd.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Url decode UTF-8 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566069/url-decode-utf-8-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `urllib.parse.unquote(s)/urllib.parse.quote(s)`

This is my code strip:

```
>>> urllib.parse.unquote("https://www.zomato.com/ncr/caf%C3%A9-mrp-connaught-place-new-delhi")
'https://www.zomato.com/ncr/café-mrp-connaught-place-new-delhi'

>>> urllib.parse.quote('https://www.zomato.com/ncr/café-mrp-connaught-place-new-delhi')
'https%3A//www.zomato.com/ncr/caf%C3%A9-mrp-connaught-place-new-delhi'
```