# Django self.kwargs returning symbols not string. any ideas?

Tags: django

in this listview: context:

```
    context['first_item'] = obj_prods.filter(m_category=self.kwargs['m_category_id'],
 category=self.kwargs['category_id'], city=self.kwargs['city']).order_by('id').first()
```

in production:
self.kwargs['city']: returning this: **%d0%91%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b5%d0%ba**
in template and in view, so filter is not working.

self.kwargs['m_category_id'] - is working as it as an integar.

but in localhost is working and returning string.
Only in productions is not working as it as a string.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Share your urls, and the `<form>` where you make this request.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to the problem:

[Url decode UTF-8 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566069/url-decode-utf-8-in-python)

from urllib.parse import unquote
url = unquote(url)

so: unquote(self.kwargs['city'])  !!!