# How to decode JSON special characters in string in python?

Tags: python, json

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get(url="news_api_here")
json_data = json.loads(r.content)

for i in range(len(json_data)):
    title = str(json_data[i]["headline"])
    print(title)
```

The output for a given title is something like this:

```
Development%2c Expansion%2c Merger%2c Acquisition%2c New Product Launches%2c and Pricing Analysis%3c%2fa%3e%3c
```

How can I decode the string to proper characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Url decode UTF-8 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566069/url-decode-utf-8-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use request's library `unquote()`

`import requests`

`requests.utils.unquote(title)`