# Invalid hex encoding in query string

Tags: python, django, search, parameters

im currently working on a DJango search with multiple query_params, since im using Sentry i found out that sometimes there's an issue triggered when you search for example something with percentages:

"100% natural" "100% unique" "50% blah blah blah"

> Sentry: Unhandled Invalid hex encoding in query string.

This is marked in the oauth lib

```
if INVALID_HEX_PATTERN.search(query):
        raise ValueError('Invalid hex encoding in query string.')
```

The current search code allows to pass any query_param like this:

```
re_path(r"^search/?$", search_system, name="search")
```

And inside the view i do have this:

```
query = request.query_params.get("query")
query = query.replace("%20", " ") if query else None
```

i tried to replace the %20 for an space, but sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesn't so it happens randomly, i don't know if im doing something wrong, or actually the question would be:

`is there anything i could do to avoid triggering this alert without doing anything in sentry? for example like cleaning up the data like a form`

Thanks in advance.

To avoid this issue i tried to set the query `replace("%20", " ")`, my best guess is that the error is triggered when you have the "percentage + space" next to each other so the url looks like

`search/100%25%20natural` which in python should be like "`100% natural`" but as i said sometimes it triggers and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Your data seems to be URL-encoded (characters not valid for a URL are "escaped") Maybe [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16566069) will help?

Comment: Does that apply to this, i can see that the url sent to the backend is: ?`query=100%25+natural` but the browser shows: `search/100%25%20natural` i can see one shows a +natural and the other %20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function for url decoding your data. space is not the only possible encoded chars...

```py
from urllib.parse import unquote

query = request.query_params.get("query")
query = unquote(query) if query else None
```